# Using a path alias to point to a folder results in a Gradle error

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

In order to point to the location of our build artifacts on a Jenkins node, we have the following gradle code:

```
def apks = file("$WORKSPACE/app/build/outputs/build-apks.tar.gz")

artifacts {
    archives apks
}
```

When I use the full path as shown below, gradle builds fine.

```
def apks = file("/var/jenkins/workspace/ui_manager_nexusDeploy/app/build/outputs/build-apks.tar.gz")
```

When we use $WORKSPACE, I get

> Could not get unknown property 'WORKSPACE' for project ':app' of type "org.gradle.api".Project. path

Ideally I'd like to use the pointer as opposed to hard-coding the path. In this reference doc, you can see that Gradle is using $buildDir just fine.https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html

Comment: Where is `$WORKSPACE` defined?

Comment: On the server. When I run "echo $WORKSPACE", I get the path printed out. I am running Gradle build on the same machine.

Comment: So `WORKSPACE` is a environment variable. You cannot directly access environment variables in Gradle, only properties or variables defined inside the Gradle build script. Load the environment variable into Gradle using `def WORKSPACE = System.getenv("WORKSPACE")`. You may then use it inside your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to access the workspace variable by "$System.env.WORKSPACE"?
ex:

```
def apks = file("$System.env.WORKSPACE"+"/app/build/outputs/build-apks.tar.gz")
```